# Launch Job unable to execute bash script, receiving abnormal code 126

Tags: bash, macos, launchd

I am trying to get my launch job to execute a bash script. The bash script will get the current datetime and store it in a text file.

This is my current plist under the directory ~/Library/LaunchAgents/:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.intern.testing</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/intern/Desktop/Python/plist_create/testing.sh</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here are the contents of my bash script (testing.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

fileName="/Users/intern/Desktop/Python/plist_create/date_time.txt"

date >> $fileName
```

However, when I executed `launchctl start com.intern.testing` (after checking the job is found in the list), I received the following error.

> Sep 30 15:55:19 interns-Mac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tlto.png) (com.user.testing[584]): Service exited with abnormal code: 126

I've made sure to give execution rights to my bash script.

[image]

I understand that there are several people who encountered the same exit code as me but those solutions didnt work for me. When I checked the meaning of exit code 126, the [link](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) stated

> Command invoked cannot execute

I'm not sure which command cannot be executed? I tried executing the bash script on its own (`./testing.sh`) and it worked.
Could someone help me?

**[UPDATE at Oct 4, 10.35am GMT+8]**

This is the updated bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

fileName = "/tmp/a.txt"

/bin/date >> "$fileName"
```

However, the updated bash script does not work too.

**[UPDATE at Oct 7, 2.50pm GMT+8]**

Based on the suggestion of @MarkSetchell, I've added the StandardErrorPath key to my plist file. Here is the updated plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.intern.testing</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
<string>/Users/intern/Desktop/Python/plist_create/testing.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/test.stderr</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And I have also updated the bash/shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

fileName="/tmp/a.txt"

/bin/date >> "$fileName"
```

When I started the launch job and accessed the stderr file, it stated `/bin/bash: /Users/intern/Desktop/Python/plist_create/testing.sh: Operation not permitted`

Is it because my script does not have enough permission? or the "current user" that is executing the script does not have enough permission?

Comment: Try writing in a file `/tmp/a` instead to see if it's a permissions issue.

Comment: Also, you should double-quote shell variables like this `date >> "$fileName"` so they still work if there are spaces in them.

Comment: `date` is not found in the PATH directories?  Try with the full path. Ex. `/bin/date`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Hello there, sorry for the late reply. I've edited the script and edited my post too but it is still unable to work.

Comment: @Nic3500 Hello, yes, i tried specifying the path too but it did not work

Comment: You cannot have spaces around your `=` sign. Use `fileName="/tmp/a.txt"`

Comment: Try adding the following to your `plist` so you capture error messages `<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/tmp/test.stderr</string>`

Comment: Hello @MarkSetchell , sorry for the late reply again. I've updated my post with the error message from the stderr file

Comment: It's probably the new security stuff from Apple. I think you'll need to click the Apple menu at top left of screen and then the "Security and Permissions" thing then run your program and it might show you what it tried to do and ask you if it should be allowed access to your desktop and HOME directory.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. Turns out you can't run scripts from the user space. If you move the script to an acceptable place like

```
/Library/Scripts
```

And I also made sure I was writing logs out to a similar place

```
/Library/Logs
```

Then make sure your permissions on the LaunchAgent or LaunchDaemon are correct with these commands:

```
chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchAgent/com.youragent.plist
```

and

```
chmod 644 /Library/LaunchAgent/com.youragent.plist
```

Then you should be good.